# FBSDKAppInviteDialog strange behaviour for dismiss and results always (null)

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to implement an app invite flow in my Ios App. This is the code i use:

```
-(void)Invite{

FBSDKAppInviteContent *content =[[FBSDKAppInviteContent alloc] init];
content.appLinkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.sdfsdfadfa.net"];

// present the dialog. Assumes self implements protocol `FBSDKAppInviteDialogDelegate`
   [FBSDKAppInviteDialog showFromViewController:self withContent:content delegate:self];
}

-(void)appInviteDialog:(FBSDKAppInviteDialog *)appInviteDialog didCompleteWithResults:(NSDictionary *)results
{

NSLog(@"result::%@",results);
}

-(void)appInviteDialog:(FBSDKAppInviteDialog *)appInviteDialog  didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
NSLog(@"error::%@",error);
}
```

this is how my app link looks like:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta property="al:ios:url" content="my-app://" />
<meta property="al:ios:app_store_id" content="fake2342" />
<meta property="al:ios:app_name" content="Myapp" />
<meta property="og:title" content="my app" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<!-- Other headers -->
</head>
<!-- Other HTML content -->
</html>
</head>
```

This is how looks like my url-scheme

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>my-app</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

The invite is correctly sended to the friends i have selected but the `appInviteDialog didCompleteWithResult` returns always '(null)' . `DidCompleteWithResult` will be lanuched only when i press "close" on the upper right side in the `FBSDKAppInviteDialog`. So i have two questions:

- It is possible to close the `FBSDKAppInviteDialog` automatically when the invites are sended (now the `FBSDKAppInviteDialog` after an invite sending, redirect to my facebook profile webpage without close itself)? I think that is the natural flow/behaviour of any modal view in ios.
- Why i receive always '(null)' from `didCompleteWithResults`? I need to know to how many friends i have sended the invite.

Comment: check on ios 8  or 9

Comment: checked, io ios 8 it returns also (null)

Comment: Make sure you haven't missed this bit: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started#delegate

Answer (score 0):

Your app link URL is incorrect, since you cannot insert any URL.

[Create an app link url](https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts). It should look like `https://fb.me/"1234567889"`.