# FBSDKAppInviteDialog check how many friends i have just invited

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working with the FBSDKAppInviteDialog in a Ios app. I have implemented my code as this question show:

[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34087793/fbsdkappinvitedialog-strange-behaviour-for-dismiss-and-results-always-null)

Until now i can't return a value different than nil from the delegate:

```
 -(void)appInviteDialog:(FBSDKAppInviteDialog *)appInviteDialog didCompleteWithResults:(NSDictionary *)results
{

NSLog(@"result::%@",results);
}
```

So i don't know the nature o the return dictionary... I need to know how many friends i have just invited in the FBSDKAppInviteDialog, this number (as i expect in a normale flow) is inside the results dictionary?

Comment: That is not possible, the invite dialog does not give you that information. (And if the reason you are asking is that you want to reward users in some way for sending out invites, please be aware that this is not allowed.)

Comment: thank you, post this comment as an answer, i'll mark it as correct

Comment: can you point me to the documentation, where is declared the that reward user  is not allowed? I can't find it...

Comment: Added an answer, plus link to Platform Policy where it says that you can not reward users for sending out inivtes. (But you can reward them for _successful_ invites.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible, the invite dialog does not give you that information.

---

And if the reason you are asking is that you want to reward users in some way for sending out invites, please be aware that this is not allowed.

This is stated in [Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#properuse), 4.5:

> “Only incentivize a person to log into your app, enter a promotion on your app’s Page, or check-in at a place. Don’t incentivize other actions.”

And the [image linked there with the question mark](https://external-frt3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQAgbSPFHr8mpJ3r&url=https%3A%2F%2Fscontent-frt3-1.xx.fbcdn.net%2Fhphotos-xfa1%2Ft39.2178-6%2F851566_549981185101135_1548011715_n.png) explains this further via some examples – as you can see, the middle one is exactly about that, rewarding users for inviting people.

You are however allowed to reward users for *successful* invites (example on the right on above image). If user A invites B, and then B acts upon that invite and joins your app, then you can reward A for *successfully* inviting a new member. If you want to implement that, then you need to read the details if the request id(s) you get passed when a user acts upon the invite, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.5#rewarding (However, that is for users arriving on your canvas only, where you will get the request id(s) passed as GET parameters. I am not aware if that is also possible if the user is redirected to the app store when they click on the invite.)

Comment: Thank you very much, the last thing... It is  valid also for an ios app that isn't a game?